# STLINK V2 not detected

Tags: arm, stm32

I have ST-LINK V2 Programmer and when I connect this with STM32MCU, it shows an error like this I have checked connections, jumper Wire.

Changed the port also. But still, it is showing No STM32 Target Found.

[Error in STM32CubeProgrammer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWeip.png)   [Error in STM32CubeIde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K47Y.png)

For checking Whether My Programmer is corrupted or not, I have checked ST-LINK with STM8 by connecting to SWIM pinout and it successfully uploads on to my STM8.

So is MY MCU corrupted or damaged, I have an STM32F103C8 Blue chip board.
And have configured its Boot Mode as shown in Pic.
[Boot Mode connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl5Uf.jpg)

BOOT 0 : 0

Boot 1: opened

Answer (score 0):

`BOOT0` and `BOOT1` pins should be grounded both. And make sure you have configured your debugging interface as SWD in CubeMX.